# Android Content-type Charset unsupported

Tags: android, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm getting an UnsupportedEncodingException because I'm gettin returned as Content-Type `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'` instead of the correct one `application/json;charset=UTF-8` (notice the ' at the end of the charset). Is there a way to just ignore this unsupported character?

The way I'm collecting the data is:

```
private static String download(String theUrl, String errorMessage) 
{
    String result = "";
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, Integer.parseInt(connectionTimeOut + "000"));
    HttpClient client = new CustomHttpClient(httpParameters).getNewHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(theUrl);
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    result = client.execute(request, handler);
    return result;
```

}

Comment: This is obviously a severe bug on the server side. Can you fix it on the server or have it fixed? Or is this outside of your area of influence?

Comment: this is outside of area. I already had a feeling it could be a bug. So i made a bug report and send it to them. Hope and see if it will be fixed soon.